# How to trigger Jenkins downstream jobs on condition based once build got success

Tags: jenkins

I have a use case like 1 Jenkins deploy and 5 different test jobs with different git repositories.

I want to trigger the specific test job once deploy job is done dynamically.

In detail:-

Deploy job name: '**A**'

Individual test job names: **P, Q, R, S, T**

once **A** job got success, then trigger job

**R** if repository url is matches with repository name **R**

else trigger

**S** if repository url is matches with repository name **S**

.....like wise

Can you please tell me how can i achieve this.?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve that by using [Conditional BuildStep Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin).

Add conditional steps as follow:

```
Build -> Add Build Step -> Conditional  Steps (multiple)
```

Then choose `Regular expression match` and have a local enviroment where you assign your *repository url* and execute your *test job* for this repository when the regular expression match this *repository url*. Create such a step for each one of your 5 repositories.

For example:

[image: Regular expression match]